# Css borders wrapping?

Tags: html, css

me and my friend are having a slight issue with our website css.  Or at least that's what we think the problem is...  The outer borders are wrapping underneath the text instead of going all the way down like they are supposed to.  Here's the css sheet we're using:

```
html {
    background-color: #00006E;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 2em 2em 4em;
    max-width: 800px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    color: #545454;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    color: #222;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 1.3em;
}

h2 {
    margin-top: 1.3em;
}

a {
    color: #0083e8; 
}

b, strong {
    font-weight: 600;
}

samp {
    display: none;
}

img {
    background: transparent;
    border: 10px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: block;
    margin: 1.3em auto;
    max-width: 95%;
    -webkit-animation: colorize 2s cubic-bezier(0, 0, .78, .36) 1;
}

@keyframes colorize {
    0% {
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes colorize {
    0% {
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    }
}
p
{
white-space:nowrap;
}
```

And here is the HTML

```
<title>Traffordcraft.net Homepage</title>

            <script src="//use.edgefonts.net/vt323.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="buttons/buttons.css" />
        </header>
    <body>
        <h1 style="font-size: 25px; color: green; font-family: vt323, sans-serif;">Welcome to traffordcraft.net, you're probably here for one of the following.  Please select one!</h1><br>
```

(Yes, there are css3 buttons under it, we have no problems with them.)

Could anybody here tell us why this is making the borders break in browser?  Thanks!

Comment: If you could attach the HTML or better yet a jsFiddle or other mockup it would be much easier to help.

Comment: I put your code in a fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/a5Rft/ - do you mean that the white background isn't the full height?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem exactly! The white background isn't the full height, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to give a `width` and `height` `100%` on `<html>` tag in CSS like below. And give a `min-height:100%` on body tag in css. check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/nivamumi/1/edit)**.

Also after seeing your code you have to add a vendor prefix for `@keyframes` as well. then only your animation will work.

```
html {
  background-color: #00006E;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

body{ min-height:100%; /*add this line*/}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want border to go down(vertical) you can use `min-height` or height in px.
We don't exactly what do you want, and we don't have your HTML code.

Try this, if I get it right:  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N5rM9/)

```
@html {
    background-color: #00006E;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

Delete background color!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the height to be of the screen, then you need to add some jQuery.

Check if this helps you.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Alotx

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  $('.innerWrap').css('minHeight',windowHeight)
})
```